# Why does gcc always give a error when i convert to float?

Tags: c, opengl, gcc

```
void init(void) 
{
   glClearColor ((float)0.0, (float)0.0, (float)0.0, (float)0.0);
   glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);
}
```

The parameter of `glClearColor` is float. But the gcc always give a warning:

```
main.c: In function ‘init’:
main.c:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
main.c:12: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
main.c:12: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
main.c:12: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
```

But i just convert a digit to float, not double, can't figure out why.

My os is mac os 64bit and the following is the `makefile`.

```
UNAME := $(shell uname)

ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
    CFLAG := -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -g -Wall -Wconversion
else
    CFLAG := -lm -lglut -lGL -lGLU -g -Wall
endif

PUB_SRC := util.c plane.c dot.c linked_dots.c controller.c time_data.c
SRC := main.c $(PUB_SRC)
TEST_SRC := test.c $(PUB_SRC)

.PHONY : main
main: $(SRC)
    gcc $(CFLAG) $(SRC)

.PHONY : test
test: $(TEST_SRC)
    gcc $(CFLAG) $(TEST_SRC)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a windows thing but I usually put something like "1.0f" if I want a float rather than casting.

Comment: @zero298 I have tried "1.0f", but the compiler just report a error.

Comment: But i written java code before, so i don't need to take care of int, float conversion error. When some code did wrong, the compiler will giving warning by default. So i just want to open a warning in gcc, to check type conversion, but won't give the warning described above.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have the same gcc compiler with your. But i do really need this warning, because the type conversion bring me a lot of troubles, but compiler just ignores it.

Comment: Try using clang, gcc is simply a symlink to llvm-gcc on current OS X, as far as I know it's transitional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you're using GCC 3.x? In GCC 3.x, the `-Wconversion` flag is documented as follows:

> Warn if a prototype causes a type conversion that is different from what
>   would happen to the same argument in the absence of a prototype.  This
>   includes conversions of fixed point to floating and vice versa, and
>   conversions changing the width or signedness of a fixed point argument
>   except when the same as the default promotion.
>
> Also, warn if a negative integer constant expression is implicitly
>   converted to an unsigned type.  For example, warn about the assignment
>   `x = -1` if `x` is unsigned.  But do not warn about explicit
>   casts like `(unsigned) -1`.

[[link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wconversion-248)]

From what I understand, the original purpose of this flag was to help detect potential problems when migrating from traditional C to ANSI C, and cases where adding a prototype could cause problems. (To be honest, it seems to me like it would have been more meaningful for the prototype itself to trigger a warning, rather than a *use* of the function, but there's probably some use I'm missing.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My gcc version is 4.1.2. So if the `-Wconversion` isn't the thing i looking for, which warning should i use. I just want to check whether i have pass a float to a function which need a int by mistake.

Comment: @user674199: Ah, O.K., in 4.1.2 it's still documented the same way ([link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wconversion-270)). In a more recent 4.x version it was changed to be more useful. As for what warning you should use instead . . . I don't know. It seems like `-Wconversion` really is the right flag for what you want, but only in newer versions. I assume that older versions don't have an appropriate flag, because if they did, `-Wconversion` wouldn't have been repurposed. Is upgrading an option?

Comment: If you use options to make sure you always have a prototype in scope, then it won't matter if you try to pass a float to a function that expects an int because the prototype will trigger conversion as necessary.  If you want to know about such conversions, `-Wconversion` is (probably) the tool, but it is going to give you false positives.  GCC 4.7.1 has the option `gcc --help=warnings` to give you information; the Apple GCC 4.2.1 does not.

Answer (score 1):

If you just put in a decimal number literal your are declaring a double. glClearColor uses floats. A double is a potentially longer number and can contain more information so by casting it to a float there is the potential for the loss of information, that's why you are getting the warning.  You can specify that you want a float by adding a f after the number.

Comment: I try to add `f` after digit again. But this time the compiler still give the same warning.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Apple-provided GCC,

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

This code:

```
extern void glClearColor(float, float, float, float);
enum { GL_FLAT = 0 };
extern void glShadeModel(int);
extern void init(void);

void init(void) 
{
   glClearColor(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glClearColor((float)0.0, (float)0.0, (float)0.0, (float)0.0);
   glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}
```

compiles with the warnings:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wconversion -c xx.c
xx.c: In function ‘init’:
xx.c:8: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
xx.c:8: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
xx.c:8: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
xx.c:8: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
xx.c:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
xx.c:9: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
xx.c:9: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
xx.c:9: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
xx.c:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
xx.c:10: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
xx.c:10: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
xx.c:10: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘glClearColor’ as ‘float’ rather than ‘double’ due to prototype
```

When compiled with GCC 4.7.1, or without the `-Wconversion`, it compiles cleanly.

You either have to edit the `makefile` to drop the `-Wconversion` warnings or live with and ignore the warnings.  Between the two, I'd drop `-Wconversion`.